# Configure a WCF RIA Service with a Secure Endpoint in web.config

Tags: .net, wcf, ria

The standard method to configure a WCF Ria Service with a secure binary endpoint (SSL) is to set RequiresSecureEndpoint = true on the EnableClientAccessAttribute as shown below:

```
[RequiresAuthentication]
[EnableClientAccess(RequiresSecureEndpoint = true)]
public class Module1DomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<AdventureWorksDataModel>
{
      .
      .
      .
}
```

I need to know if the RequiresSecureEndpoint = true option can be set in the web.config file or if there's an equivalent method to restrict a WCF RIA Service to only a secure endpoint (SSL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSFT it is not possible to do this from the web.config, see [MSDN WCF Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/98a4aebd-55ea-4f3f-9740-9b571c530ecb).

If interested in having this feature being added to WCF RIA Services, vote-up this [suggestion](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services/suggestions/2376015-restrict-wcf-ria-service-binary-endpoint-to-secure?ref=title) on the [WCF RIA Services Forum](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services).